# Openshift Online STOMP over EAP (HornetQ) port configuration

Tags: openshift, hornetq, stomp, jboss-eap-6

I have the solution working on a local environment. The problem is when the application outside the EAP gear tries to connect to the Stomp port.

How can I expose the new port for STOMP on Openshift online to another application on my openshift domain?

Answer (score 0):

You would not be able to expose the STOMP port for public use, though you could do a port forward from your local workstation to use it.  The only ports that are available publicly on OpenShift are 80/443/8000/8443